# Using JSON with pandas, problem with nested info (python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, nested, normalize

I am trying to use a `JSON` file to create a table with `pandas`.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize


releves = pd.read_json('DataTP2.json')
releves
```

My file is structured the following way:

```
[
  {
    "trimestre":"H2012",
    "cours":[
      {
        "sigle":"TECH 20701",
        "titre":"La cybersécurité et le gestionnaire",
        "etudiants":[
          {
            "matricule":"22003545",
            "nom":"Lahaie,Olivier",
            "note":"A+",
            "valeur": 4.3
          },
```

and so on.

When using read_json, the table does not show the info nested and instead shows every less indented items as one line as such:

`|Cours|Trimestre|`

My desired output would be:

`|etudiant|nom|matricule|note|valeur|sigle|titre|trimestre|`

I have tried using `normalize_json`, but I get the following error:

**`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'itervalues'`**

I have tried to convert to a dictionary before using normalize, but another error pops up.
Can anyone help me get out of this roadblock?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey this should flatten your json

```
json_normalize(arr, record_path=['cours', 'etudiants'], 
           meta=['trimestre', ['cours', 'sigle'], ['cours', 'titre']], 
           record_prefix='etudiant_')
```

Comment: This didn't work when using pd.read_json but it did when using "open with", any idea why? thanks

Comment: `pd.read_json` does not normalize your json. "open with" is needed for `json_normalize` as it takes a python obj as input